# Nested number and bullet lists

Tags: css, list

have the following code in my CSS to achieve stacked numbering for nested lists (i.e. 1, 1.1, 1.2, etc.)

```
ol { counter-reset: item }
ol li { display: block }
ol li:before { content: counters(item, ".") ". "; counter-increment: item }
```

However, I'm finding that this is interfering with the list type when I have a bullet list embedded within a numbered list.

```
  <ol class="numberList">
    <li>
      List 9 – Multi-level mixed bullets &amp; numbers (Custom)
      <ul class="bulletList">
        <li>
          SHOULD BE A BULLET List 9 – Multi-level mixed bullets &amp; numbers (Custom)
          <ol class="numberList">
            <li>
              List 9 -- Multi-level mixed bullets &amp; numbers (Custom)
            </li>
            <li>
              List 9 -- Multi-level mixed bullets &amp; numbers (Custom)
            </li>
          </ol>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ol>
```

I should get a bullet in the first nested list, however, I am getting a number "2" instead.

How can I get the bullet list to be honored with my numbering for nested lists?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The selector `ol li` means *any* `li` element that is a [descendant](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#descendant-combinators) of `ol`. So if you have `<ol><li><ul><li>` then the latter `li` will also be matched.

To change that, you can use the [child combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#child-combinators) which will only match the layer directly below:

```
ol > li { ... }
ol > li:before { ... }
```

Comment: Thank you! That was what I needed. Here is a jsfiddle to show the fix in action. http://jsfiddle.net/6xQME/1/